# Microsoft Word Subtract constant from date's year

Tags: date, syntax, ms-word, constants, subtraction

How can I subtract a constant from the current date's year in Ms-Word?

**Attempt**

```
{ = {DATE\@"YYYY"} – 1983 \#"00" }
```

I keep getting:
`!Syntax Error, {`

Comment: Are the field braces for the YEAR field created via Insert|Field or Ctrl-F9? You can't just type them in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try { = { Date @ "yyyy" } - 1983 }

Or

```
{ = { Date \@ "yyyy" } - 1983 \# 00 }
```

**ALL** of the field delimiter braces must be created using **Ctrl+F9**. That includes the ones for the Date *field*.

See Word MVP Graham Mayor's [macro or Add-In to convert text representations of fields to true fields](http://www.gmayor.com/export_field.htm).

**References:**

- [Dealing With Fields in Word](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/dealing-with-fields-in-microsoft-word/e1bdddad-5a51-4327-837c-c3786c16a501) - my article on Microsoft Site
- my page on [Using Date Fields in Word](https://addbalance.com/word/datefields1.htm#PageStart)
- [Word Date Calculations Tutorial](http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38719-microsoft-word-date-calculation-tutorial.html) by Paul Edstein (macropod) - the definitive work on the subject

Comment: I typed Ctrl-F9 and wrote by hand "= { Date @ "yyyy" } - 1983". See [video](https://imgur.com/a/eC5ZcUW).

Comment: ALL of the braces must be created using Ctrl+F9. That includes the ones for the Date field. REFERENCES: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/dealing-with-fields-in-microsoft-word/e1bdddad-5a51-4327-837c-c3786c16a501 https://addbalance.com/word/datefields1.htm#PageStart http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38719-microsoft-word-date-calculation-tutorial.html

Comment: That was the missing piece. Now it works.

Comment: Glad to have helped.